# Cakephp - fighting with 'thechaw' on git

Tags: git, cakephp, ssh, authentication, ssh-keys

I feel like I tried everything to clone http://thechaw.com/source from git with no success.  I have a create SSH keys in order to access this git and I believe I followed the directions but I'm missing something easy.

I followed all the instructions (http://thechaw.com/wiki/guides/setup).  Can someone tell me what I'm going wrong?

1. First:

   `% cd ~/.ssh && sh-keygen`
2. Added my key to their "account" section (I assume the key leaves off the "ssh-ras" and the "me@mydomain"`
3. Then:

   `% git config --global user.name "<My git Username>"`

   `% git config --global user.email <My git Email address>`
4. Now I try to clone using

   `% sudo git clone git@thechaw.com:chaw.git`

I always receive:

```
Initialized empty Git repository in /var/www/chaw/chaw/.git/
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I've been trying for many hours.  What am I missing?  I have a github account and I even put my ssh key in there (but I believe that shouldn't have any effect).

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't be leaving off anything from the contents of the id_rsa.pub file. Include the ssh-rsa bit and such.

Comment: Thanks.  Tried that.  Same error.

Comment: My email address at the end of my SSH key does NOT match my git email. Would that matter?

Comment: I don't know what thechaw is, but this is probably not the best way to reach their tech support.  Their ssh daemon is refusing your key.

Comment: They never answer.  I know I'm missing something very simple, just can't figure out what... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you added the ssh key and Git configuration to your non-root user, but then used "sudo" to do the clone thereby making Git not find your user's keys (since it's running as root).

Comment: curious - what are you cloning from thechaw? Cake's main dev is on github now and thechaw application source is pretty rough around the edges.

Answer (score 1):

spent quite some time and this is how i finally did it. i couldnt get it running on rsa so i tried dsa and then it just worked:

```
ssh-keygen -t dsa -C "myemailIUsedAtthechaw.com"


cat ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub | xclip -sel clip
```

then just went into my account at thechaw and pasted it into the git key field.

then i

```
git clone git@thechaw.com:chaw.git
```

n it checked out. wat a relief. :)